# How to use decltype to determine the result of an addition

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

With `decltype` I can do the following:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(T1 const & t1, T2 const & T2)
-> decltype(t1+t2)
{ /* ... */ }
```

However, in my case I need to find out the type of an addition without having instances of the types `T1` and `T2`. Concretely:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class Matrix
{
    /* ... */
    public:
        template <typename CompatibleType>
        auto operator+(Matrix<CompatibleType> const & other)
        -> Matrix<decltype(ValueType+CompatibleType)>
        { /* ... */ }
};
```

Of course, `decltype(ValueType+CompatibleType)` does not work this way. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Look into `std::declval`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`std::declval<T>();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) (C++11):

```
#include <utility>

template <typename CompatibleType>
 auto operator+(Matrix<CompatibleType> const & other)
  -> Matrix<decltype(std::declval<ValueType>() + std::declval<CompatibleType>())>
    { /* ... */ }
```

`std::declval` returns an rvalue-reference, and will only work in an unevaluated-context, which `decltype` happens to be.

If your compiler doesn't support this Standard, use this pointer trick (which also only works in an unevaluated-context):

```
-> Matrix<decltype(*(ValueType*)(0) + *(CompatibleType*)(0))>
// or
-> Matrix<decltype(*static_cast<ValueType*>(0) +
                   *static_cast<CompatibleType*>(0))>
```

Comment: If I could I would mark all three answers, but since I can't I will go with the one that provides the most information. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK `declval` has the advantage that it work on references, as it's illegal to make a pointer out of a reference.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `std::declval` for that:

```
decltype(std::declval<A>()+std::declval<B>))
```

Answer (score 6):

You need/want `std::declval`:

```
decltype(std::declval<ValueType>()+std::declval<CompatibleType>());
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::declval` works, but there's a simpler answer hiding inside the ... -- real element access!

Assuming your `Matrix` class has an `at` function like `std::vector`, you can write

```
template<typename M>
auto operator+(M const & other)
     -> Matrix<decltype(this->at(0,0) + other.at(0,0))>
```

Otherwise, replace `at` with the correct function name which is used inside the `operator+` body to access the individual elements.

This has the further advantage that **it works on any `other` parameter which provides the needed accessor function, it doesn't have to be another `Matrix<T>` at all**.  That's called *duck typing*, and is why you should use the same accessor function that your function body actually uses.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but assuming `ValueType` and `CompatibleType` are POD types or other classes that have a public argument-free constructor (probably a valid assumption for your use-case), you can just construct those types. So

```
decltype(ValueType+CompatibleType)
```

does not work (as you wrote) but

```
decltype(ValueType() + CompatibleType())
```

does and there's no runtime overhead (Source: [here](https://arne-mertz.de/2017/01/decltype-declval/)). You don't need `std::declval` in this case.

Proof: [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1mWPO0jb)